# Google not indexing New Forum

Tags: seo, google, 301-redirect, sitemap, search-engine-indexing

Over two months ago we installed a new forum system to our website. The new platform uses a different URL pattern, therefore we have installed a global 301 redirect, from old to new. We have updated the sitemap with all the new URLS but Google still hasn't refreshed its index, or at least that is reported by Google Webmaster Tools:

- 150,00 URL Submitted
- 50,00 URL Indexed

[image: Webmaster Tools Console, index drop]

Comment: Was the old forum on the subdomain or different domain?

Comment: New forum was in same location (scirra.com/forum) although I think it might of been over HTTP not HTTPS

Comment: Were they even indexed in Google from the original site? Did the URL's change or remain the same? When you say new forum, did you change forum software?

Comment: @zigojacko, the URLs changed, and we changed forum software yes (went from WebWiz (classic ASP) to PHPBB3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does fetch as Googlebot say? As it looks from this end you are not showing Google the content, instead returning this "You are not authorised to read this forum."

Comment: When I try to fetch as Googlebot, it can't render it as the default protocol is HTTP, my site forces HTTPS so fetch as Google always returns "redirected" and I can't seem to preview it.

What tool are you using to fetch as Googlebot?

Comment: Ahh thanks, this was the reason!  PHPBB needs to set Bot group to "Readonly".  Got fetch as google working by adding new site in webmaster tools specifying https as Google treat them as separate sites.